# csvtojson conversion using Nodejs gives gibberish data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv, npm

I am trying to convert a csv file to json using csvtojson converter in nodejs.My code is as shown below.
I get an output of data as shown below. I am not sure why this is happening and how to prevent it.

```
var Converter  = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream("input.csv");

var converter = new Converter({constructResult:false});

converter.on("end_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
  var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
  var file     = 'output.json';
  jsonfile.writeFile(file, jsonObj, function (err) { console.error(err); });});


fileStream.pipe(converter);
```

{"��P\u0000a\u0000c\u0000k\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000":"\u0000c\u0000o\u0000m\u0000.\u0000t\u0000r\u0000i\u0000n\u0000e\u0000t\u0000.\u0000h\u0000r\u0000p\u0000m\u0000o\u0000b\u0000i\u0000l\u0000e\u0000","\u0000A\u0000p\u0000p\u0000 \u0000V\u0000e\u0000r\u0000s\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000 \u0000C\u0000o\u0000d\u0000e\u0000":"\u00006\u00002\u0000","\u0000R\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000e\u0000w\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000L\u0000a\u0000n\u0000g\u0000u\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u0000":"\u0000e\u0000n\u0000","\u0000D\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000c\u0000e\u0000":"\u0000","\u0000R\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000e\u0000w\u0000 \u0000S\u0000u\u0000b\u0000m\u0000i\u0000t\u0000 \u0000D\u0000a\u0000t\u0000e\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000T\u0000i\u0000m\u0000e\u0000":"\u00002\u00000\u00001\u00005\u0000-\u00001\u00002\u0000-\u00002\u00002\u0000T\u00000\u00003\u0000:\u00003\u00002\u0000:\u00003\u00008\u0000Z\u0000","\u0000R\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000e\u0000w\u0000 \u0000S\u0000u\u0000b\u0000m\u0000i\u0000t\u0000 \u0000M\u0000i\u0000l\u0000l\u0000i\u0000s\u0000 \u0000S\u0000i\u0000n\u0000c\u0000e\u0000 \u0000E\u0000p\u0000o\u0000c\u0000h\u0000":"\u00001\u00004\u00005\u00000\u00007\u00005\u00005\u00001\u00005\u00008\u00002\u00006\u00002\u0000","\u0000R\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000e\u0000w\u0000 \u0000L\u0000a\u0000s\u0000t\u0000 \u0000U\u0000p\u0000d\u0000a\u0000t\u0000e\u0000 \u0000D\u0000a\u0000t\u0000e\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000T\u0000i\u0000m\u0000e\u0000":"\u00002\u00000\u00001\u00005\u0000-\u00001\u00002\u0000-\u00002\u00002\u0000T\u00000\u00003\u0000:\u00003\u00002\u0000:\u00003\u00008\u0000Z\u0000","\u0000R\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000e\u0000w\u0000 \u0000L\u0000a\u0000s\u0000t\u0000 \u0000U\u0000p\u0000d\u0000a\u0000t\u0000e\u0000 \u0000M\u0000i\u0000l\u0000l\u0000i\u0000s\u0000 \u0000S\u0000i\u0000n\u0000c\u0000e\u0000 \u0000E\u0000p\u0000o\u0000c\u0000h\u0000":"\u00001\u00004\u00005\u00000\u00007\u00005\u00005\u00001\u00005\u00008\u00002\u00006\u00002\u0000","\u0000S\u0000t\u0000a\u0000r\u0000 \u0000R\u0000a\u0000t\u0000i\u0000n\u0000g\u0000":"\u00005\u0000","\u0000R\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000e\u0000w\u0000 \u0000T\u0000i\u0000t\u0000l\u0000e\u0000":"\u0000","\u0000R\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000e\u0000w\u0000 \u0000T\u0000e\u0000x\u0000t\u0000":"\u0000","\u0000D\u0000e\u0000v\u0000e\u0000l\u0000o\u0000p\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000R\u0000e\u0000p\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000D\u0000a\u0000t\u0000e\u0000 \u0000a\u0000n\u0000d\u0000 \u0000T\u0000i\u0000m\u0000e\u0000":"\u0000","\u0000D\u0000e\u0000v\u0000e\u0000l\u0000o\u0000p\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000R\u0000e\u0000p\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000M\u0000i\u0000l\u0000l\u0000i\u0000s\u0000 \u0000S\u0000i\u0000n\u0000c\u0000e\u0000 \u0000E\u0000p\u0000o\u0000c\u0000h\u0000":"\u0000","\u0000D\u0000e\u0000v\u0000e\u0000l\u0000o\u0000p\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000R\u0000e\u0000p\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000T\u0000e\u0000x\u0000t\u0000":"\u0000","\u0000R\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000e\u0000w\u0000 \u0000L\u0000i\u0000n\u0000k\u0000":"\u0000"},
{"��P\u0000a\u0000c\u0000k\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000":"\u0000"}

Comment: What does your input.csv look like? What is its encoding?

Comment: I can see �. So I suppose it is UTF-8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved this issue: It was an encoding issue: correct code was "utf16 "

```
   var csvEncoding = { encoding: 'utf16le' }; 
    var csvString = fs.readFileSync(csvfile, csvEncoding).toString(); 
    converter.fromString(csvString, function(err,result){ 
    //your code here console.log(err); 
    console.log(result); 

});
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: How to check if it needs to change encoding?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue to OP but was using `csv-parse` with a file coming out of S3.

Thanks to OP I got on the right path with an encoding issue, I was able to resolve my issue by using `utf16le` in my stream coupled with `iconv-lite` like so:

```
s3
  .getObject(getObjectParams)
  .createReadStream()
  .on('end', () => cb(null))
  .pipe(iconv.decodeStream('utf16le'))
  .pipe(parse({ delimiter: '\t', columns: true }))
  .pipe(transformer);
```

Hopefully this helps others in the same boat!

Answer (score 0):

```
var Converter  = require("csvtojson").Converter;

var fs  = require('fs');
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream("input.csv");

var converter = new Converter({constructResult:true});
converter.on("end_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
  var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
  var file     = 'output.json';
  console.log(jsonObj);
  jsonfile.writeFile(file, jsonObj, function (err,result) {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(result) ;
  });
});

fileStream.pipe(converter);
```

Comment: This code is almost the same as what I did. It works for certain examples that I take off the internet. It is not working for my file in particular. The data is being read as expected, but it is not being written as expected. I notice some characters such as "��" in the file. Is this an issue? The file permissions are the same as any other file. So that is not the issue.

Comment: I resolved this issue: It was an encoding issue: correct code was "utf16 "        var csvEncoding = { encoding: 'utf16le' };
  var csvString = fs.readFileSync(csvfile, csvEncoding).toString();

  converter.fromString(csvString, function(err,result){
     //your code here
     console.log(err);
     console.log(result);
   });

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your inputs